# Virtualization solutions under OpenBSD

Tags: virtual-machine, openbsd

I use "OpenBSD as my Desktop OS". What are my choices to run a Linux Distribution, or a Windows (XP/7) in a Virtual Machine?

I know that the following apps are not available for OBSD:

- VirtualBox
- XEN

Comment: I know that both KVM and QEMU are available on FreeBSD, but I'm not sure about OpenBSD.

Comment: Please stop using "e.g" and "what if"s in your questions, they only confuse matters. Just ask!

Comment: From Wikipedia it seems that QEMU is the only option: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) is available for BSD, although it looks like you might have to do a little fiddling to get it to go based on NetBSD packages. Here is a guy that got [Windows to run in QEMU on OpenBSD](http://www.cromwell-intl.com/unix/openbsd-qemu-windows-howto.html).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use Qemu in 5.0 - http://www.dannosite.com/?q=node/178 , but the kqemu software that used to speed up Qemu is now gone, because the parent project no longer uses it. This means using an older version of Qemu that supports KQemu, or the newer non-KQemu Qemu.

Both are in packages.

Answer (score 1):

Since quite recently, OpenBSD has the ability to run virtual machines natively using `vmd(8)`, a virtual machine daemon.

See [vmd(8)](http://man.openbsd.org/vmd.8), [vmctl(8)](http://man.openbsd.org/vmctl.8) and [vm.conf(5)](http://man.openbsd.org/vm.conf.5) for details.

The following blog works through an installation of an OpenBSD VM on top of OpenBSD 6.1, but I know for a fact that people have also been running various Linuxes in `vmd`: http://blog.hermes-technology.de/openbsd/server/virtualmachine/network/2017/06/12/vmd-for-a-virtual-server-network.html